# JSON will not display

Tags: ruby, json, html, web, sinatra

I have a Sinatra application that should get image URLs from a JSON file and put them into HTML `<img>` tags.

I can parse through the JSON just fine when I print it to the command line, but when I use ERB to place the data, it won't show.

I put it in `<ul>` tags and got only the bullet points for every image in the JSON file.

Here is my code:

app.rb:

```
get "/" do

    file = open("./images.json")
    json = file.read

    @parsed = JSON.parse(json)

    erb :roar

    #@parsed.each do |roar|
    #  p roar["url"]
    #end

end
```

Roar.erb:

```
<ul>
 <% @parsed.each do |shop| %>
 <li> <%shop["url"] %> </li>

 <% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you not just missing an "=" here :

```
<li> <%= shop["url"] %> </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just some comments on the code in general:

Don't use:

```
file = open("./images.json")
json = file.read

@parsed = JSON.parse(json)
```

Instead, use:

```
json = File.open("./images.json") do |fi|
  fi.read
end

@parsed = JSON.parse(json)
```

Or:

```
json = File.open("./images.json") { |fi| fi.read }
@parsed = JSON.parse(json)
```

Or:

```
json = File.read("./images.json")
@parsed = JSON.parse(json)
```

Or:

```
@parsed = JSON.parse(File.read("./images.json"))
```

The reasons are:

- `file = open("./images.json")` opens the file but never closes it. That's not good form, and it's also not idiomatic Ruby. The first two replacements automatically close the opened file.
- Using `File.read` returns the contents of the file just as opening it and reading in a separate step, only it's all in one step. The file is also automatically closed afterwards.